# psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL: role "postgresql" does not exist

Tags: django, postgresql

I am a postresql novice.
When I was ready to migrate INSTALLED_APPS in 'settings' to database,there appeared the following error:

```
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "postgresql" does not exist
```

and I have displayed the full exception message:

```
c:\fanhuaxiu\Scripts>activate
(fanhuaxiu) c:\fanhuaxiu\Scripts>cd ..

(fanhuaxiu) c:\fanhuaxiu>cd fhx

(fanhuaxiu) c:\fanhuaxiu\fhx>python manage.py migrate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\fanhuaxiu\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 216, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\fanhuaxiu\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 194, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\fanhuaxiu\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 168, in get_new_connection
    connection = Database.connect(**conn_params)

  File "C:\fanhuaxiu\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 130, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: FATAL:  role "postgresql" does not exist
```

It has taken me nearly 2 hours to find a solution and failed 233333.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you create the role "postgresql" you are using in your settings file?

Comment: Sounds like your user in the django settings for database does not exist in the PostGreSQL database.  For example if your user is 'webuser' in the django settings then you need to have a role created in PostGre for 'webuser'

See the docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#databases

Comment: DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'blog',
        'USER': 'postgresql',
        'PASSWORD': 'shoot',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}     A user had been configured like that before the exception.And the doc exactly was what I referred to yesterday.So it baffles me if python3.6 is correctly connected to the database in my computer.

Comment: Thank u so much.It turns out that I'm so stupid to set postgresql as postgres.